# Smart Pointers and Ref Counting in Java

Tags: java, smart-pointers, refcounting

I'm trying to write DagNode class in Java whereby two nodes are logically equal iff they are equal as references.

The idea in C++ —(I'm from C++)— would be to use smart pointers and reference counting:

- When a node is created, I'll look up in some table if that node already exists. If so, I'll return a pointer to the old one. Otherwise, make anew node.
- Overloaded C++ methods like copy constructors and destructors will do ref-counting, and when the ref-count of a node drops to 0, the node is evicted from the above-mentioned table. (C++ will also free the memory.)

However, there seems to be no way to automatically do ref-counting in Java. I'll need to do ref-counting to know when to evict a node from the table (so that it can be garbage collected), and I really want to avoid calling `node->incRef()` and `node->decRef()` at the start and end of each function.

How do we do this C++ idiom in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, the reference survey and the garbage are automatic.

But that doesn't mean it's entirely hidden.

You seem to need [ReferenceQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) if you want to know when an object can be garbaged, and maybe [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) if you want to keep pointers which don't prevent the garbage.

I suggest you have a look at the description of the [java.lang.ref package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html) to find the best solution for your need.

Comment: Reference-counting in Java is not automatic - Java GC does not rely on reference-counting at all.

Comment: Allow me to repeat this back to you to make sure I understand.  Basically I have a table of WeakReference's and the point of the ReferenceQueue is to evict the WeakReference from the table when it gets GC'd anyways.  Having a WeakReference in the table means that it can still be GC'd, but if there is a regular reference on the stack or in some other object then it cannot be GC'd.  And the ReferenceQueue makes sure that the eviction from the table happens BEFORE the garbage collection, so everything is good.

Comment: That is a surprisingly elegant solution!  It isn't so often that I'm impressed by Java.

Answer (score 2):

> When a node is created, you look up in some table if that node already exists and if so just return a pointer to the old one, else make the new node.

Making this look-up mechanism in Java is not that difficult. Just use a factory method, which checks a 'table' and returns that same instance if it already exists.

> I need the reference counting so I know when to evict a node from the table (so it can be garbage collected)

For that Java has the `WeakReference` class. It does not allow you to do reference counting, but allows the object to be GC-ed when nobody references it anymore.

Combine these 2 and you can

- construct a 'table' populated with `WeakReference`s
- use one of the available Java `Collection` implementations which uses `WeakReference`s (for example a `WeakHashmap`)

Answer (score 0):

Reference counting for the purpose of deterministic resource management can be implemented in Java. It can be useful if you are using any kind of system resource that is not managed by the GC directly. The GC manages heap memory. However, if you are using any other kind of resource such as file handles, network sockets, or *native memory*, you cannot rely on the GC (or its mechanisms, such as finalization or ReferenceQueue) because you may find that you've allocated all of your resource but the GC still hasn't started since there is plenty of Java heap memory left. (Be very careful about using finalization/ReferenceQueue--[they should never be relied upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879761/should-java-9-cleaner-be-preferred-to-finalization))

Take a look at [almson-refcount](https://github.com/almson/almson-refcount). It is a library I created for reference counting after I could not find any stand-alone alternative. It is pretty simple and inspired by another, mature framework.

---

Regarding the OP's question, it is unclear what they actually need. They're definitely not using system resources. It sounds like they want a HashMap parallel to their DAG for the purpose of optimizing `get`. The obvious way to do it is to make the DAG doubly-linked and remove nodes from the map when they're removed from the DAG. They don't need WeakReferences or general-purpose reference counting for that, although either could perhaps be used.