# Should Java 9 Cleaner be preferred to finalization?

Tags: java, java-9, finalizer, finalize, finalization

In Java, overriding the `finalize` method gets a bad rap, although I don't understand why. Classes like `FileInputStream` use it to ensure `close` gets called, in both Java 8 and Java 10. Nevertheless, Java 9 introduced `java.lang.ref.Cleaner` which uses the PhantomReference mechanism instead of GC finalization. At first, I thought it was just a way add finalization to third-party classes. However, the example given in [its javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) shows a use-case that can easily be rewritten with a finalizer.

Should I be rewriting all of my `finalize` methods in terms of Cleaner? (I don't have many, of course. Just some classes that use OS resources particularly for CUDA interop.)

As I can tell, Cleaner (via PhantomReference) avoids some of the dangers of `finalizer`. In particular, you don't have any access to the cleaned object and so you can't resurrect it or any of its fields.

However, that is the only advantage I can see. Cleaner is also non-trivial. In fact, it and finalization both use a `ReferenceQueue`! (Don't you just love how easy it is to read the JDK?) Is it faster than finalization? Does it avoid waiting for two GCs? Will it avoid heap exhaustion if many objects are queued for cleanup? (The answer to all of those would appear to me to be no.)

Finally, there's actually nothing guaranteeing to stop you from referencing the target object in the cleaning action. Be careful to read the long API Note! If you do end up referencing the object, the whole mechanism will silently break, unlike finalization which always tries to limp along. Finally, while the finalization thread is managed by the JVM, creating and holding Cleaner threads is your own responsibility.

Comment: Probably. Java 9 [deprecated `finalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--). The Javadoc does ***explicitly*** say *The Cleaner and PhantomReference provide more flexible and efficient ways to release resources when an object becomes unreachable.*

Comment: JFYI in java 9 in contrast with java 8 we have to use PhantomReference for **post-mortem** cleanup. So when if we found **PhantomReference** instance in a queue it means that memory for referenced object was free. In java 8 we had to execure **clean** method explicitly to free memory

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Use neither.**

Trying to recover from resource leaks using `Cleaner` presents nearly as many challenges as `finalize` the worst of which, as mentioned by Holger, is premature finalization (which is a problem not only with `finalize` but with every kind of soft/weak/phantom reference). Even if you do your best to implement finalization correctly (and, again, I mean any kind of system that uses a soft/weak/phantom reference), you can never guarantee that the resource leaks won't lead to resource exhaustion. The unavoidable fact is that the GC doesn't know about your resources.

Instead, you should assume that resources will be closed correctly (via `AutoCloseable`, `try-with-resources`, reference counting, etc.), find and fix bugs rather than hope to work around them, and *use finalization (in any of its forms) only as a debugging aid, much like `assert`*.

## **Resource leaks must be fixed--not worked around.**

Finalization should only be used as an assertion mechanism to (try to) notify you that a bug exists. To that end, I suggest taking a look at the Netty-derived [almson-refcount](https://github.com/almson/almson-refcount). It offers an efficient resource leak **detector** based on weak references, and an optional reference-counting facility that is more flexible than the usual AutoCloseable. What makes its leak detector great is that it offers different levels of tracking (with different amounts of overhead) and you can use it to capture stack traces of where your leaked objects are allocated and used.

Comment: A leak is something different.  You can have memory leaks, yet nobody claims the garbage collector should fix those.  Memory is a resource like any other, which preferably is released ASAP.  For the memory resource there is a standard mechanism.  This mechanism should be available for other types of resources as well.  There will be situations where you want to release such resources as quick as possible, but there are far more where "eventually" is just fine, as already seen in many applications that donot close sockets, files, etc, and still manage to work fine thanks to finalization.

Comment: @john16384 Did you read the part about premature finalization? Also, do you really not close your files? Your comment is so messed up, I am shocked you call yourself a "Java specialist."

Comment: Strange, @AleksandrDubinsky  that those many applications which don't explicitly close files or sockets but use finalize _do_ work just fine.

Comment: @barneypitt Who are you? How did you form this opinion? Is there a cult of really bad Java programmers somewhere who teach each other not to close files and sockets? Every single Java tutorial and book teaches to close files. I'm honestly curious about your microcosm.

Comment: I clearly said that applications _which use finalize_ to to close files and sockets seem to work just fine. This is not "not closing them". It is not closing them immediately. And for that matter I didn't say I condone it (it would obviously be unwise in a heavily loaded server). Just that such applications _do_ seem to work fine, as per @john16384's comment. You were a rude, supercilious smartass towards him, yet failed to cite any evidence which refuted his claim. You still haven't. I'm pulling you up for it. Where is it?

Comment: @barneypitt "Seem" to work fine? Great argument. I'll explain the problems with finalization that you can read anywhere else, if you leave me alone. OSes have limits on open files and sockets. However, finalization runs when the GC is out of *memory*, **not** when the process or OS *is out of file or socket handles*. It's a broken concept, unless a file-, socket-, and everything-aware GC is introduced. Will an application that only opens a single file work fine? Even that's not guaranteed, because of the *premature finalization* problem introduced in Java 8.

Comment: Introduced and fixed. If a bug is introduced in intrinsic locks, do you propose use of "synchronized" is inherently dangerous and should never be used? "Seem to work fine" <=> "work fine". Desktop apps which read the occasional properties file and don't explicitly close them, objectively are fine. Finalization does _not_ happen just when the application runs out of memory. Garbage collection is generational. Resources like sockets/file readers tend to have fleeting lifetimes and never leave Eden space. Eden space objects are collected very frequently, regardless of memory use.

Comment: @barneypitt Do you mean that premature finalization has been fixed? Can you share a source? Various GCs work differently. ZGC isn't generational (yet) and doesn't preemptively run at all (without an opt-in flag). And of course, the contract of `finalize` doesn't promise anything. Keeping even a single config file open can cause various problems depending on platform, from preventing filesystem unmounting to preventing the file from being modified (windows).

Answer (score 25):

You are not supposed to replace all `finalize()` methods with a `Cleaner`. The fact that the deprecation of `finalize()` method and the introduction of (a `public`) `Cleaner` happened in the same Java version, only indicates that a general work on the topic happened, not that one is supposed to be a substitute of the other.

Other related work of that Java version is the removal of the rule that a `PhantomReference` is not automatically cleared (yes, before Java 9, using a `PhantomReference` instead of `finalize()` still required two GC cycles to reclaim the object) and the introduction of [`Reference.reachabilityFence(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence-java.lang.Object-).

The first alternative to `finalize()`, is not to have a garbage collection dependent operation at all. It’s good when you say that you don’t have many, but I’ve seen entirely obsolete `finalize()` methods in the wild. The problem is that `finalize()` looks like an ordinary `protected` method and the tenacious myth that `finalize()` was some kind of destructor still is spread on some internet pages. Marking it *deprecated* allows to signal to the developer that this is not the case, without breaking compatibility. Using a mechanism requiring explicit registration helps understanding that this is not the normal program flow. And it doesn’t hurt when it looks more complicated than overriding a single method.

In case your class does encapsulate a non-heap resource, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--) states:

> Classes whose instances hold non-heap resources should provide a method to enable explicit release of those resources, and they should also implement [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) if appropriate.

(so that’s the preferred solution)

> The [Cleaner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) and [PhantomReference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) provide more flexible and efficient ways to release resources when an object becomes unreachable.

So when you truly need interaction with the garbage collector, even this brief documentation comment names *two* alternatives, as `PhantomReference` is not mentioned as the hidden-from-developer backend of `Cleaner` here; using `PhantomReference` directly is an alternative to `Cleaner`, which might be even more complicated to use, but also provides even more control over timing and threads, including the possibility to cleanup within the same thread which used the resource. (Compare to `WeakHashMap`, which has such cleanup avoiding the expenses of thread safe constructs). It also allows dealing with exceptions thrown during the cleanup, in a better way than silently swallowing them.

But even `Cleaner` solves more problems that you are aware of.

A significant problem, is the time of registration.

- An object of a class with a nontrivial `finalize()` method is registered when the `Object()` constructor has been executed. At this point, the object has not been initialized yet. If your initialization is terminated with an exception, the `finalize()` method still will be called. It might be tempting to solve this by the object’s data, e.g. setting an `initialized` flag to `true`, but you can only say this for your own instance data, but not for data of a subclass, which still has not been initialized when your constructor returns.

  Registering a cleaner requires a fully constructed `Runnable` holding all necessary data for the cleanup, without a reference to the object under construction. You may even defer the registration when the resource allocation did not happen in the constructor (think of an unbound `Socket` instance or a `Frame` which is not atomically connected to a display)
- A `finalize()` method can be overridden, without calling the superclass method or failing to do this in the exceptional case. Preventing the method from overriding, by declaring it `final`, does not allow the subclasses to have such cleanup actions at all. In contrast, every class may register cleaners without interference to the other cleaners.

Granted, you could have solved such issues with encapsulated objects, however, the design of having a `finalize()` method for every class guided to the other, wrong direction.

- As you already discovered, there is a `clean()` method, which allows to perform the cleanup action immediately and removing the cleaner. So when providing an explicit close method or even implementing `AutoClosable`, this is the preferred way of cleanup, timely disposing the resource and getting rid of all the problems of garbage collector based cleanup.

  Note that this harmonizes with the points mentioned above. There can be multiple cleaners for an object, e.g. registered by different classes in the hierarchy. Each of them can be triggered individually, with an intrinsic solution regarding access rights, only who registered the cleaner gets hands on the associated `Cleanable` to be able to invoke the `clean()` method.

---

That said, it is often overlooked that the worst thing that can happen when managing resources with the garbage collector, is not that the cleanup action may run later or never at all. The worst thing that can happen, is that it runs *too early*. See [finalize() called on strongly reachable object in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488) for example. Or, a really nice one, [JDK-8145304, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(runnable) throws RejectedExecutionException](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145304), where a finalizer shuts down the executor service still in use.

Granted, just using `Cleaner` or `PhantomReference` does not solve this. But removing finalizers and implementing an alternative mechanism when truly needed, is an opportunity to carefully think about the topic and perhaps insert [`reachabilityFence`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence-java.lang.Object-) where needed. The worst thing you can have, is a method that looks like being easy-to-use, when in fact, the topic is horribly complex and 99% of its use are potentially breaking some day.

Further, while the alternatives are more complex, you said yourself, they are rarely needed. This complexity should only affect a fraction of your code base. Any why should `java.lang.Object`, the base class for all classes, host a method addressing a rare corner case of Java programming?

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! And yet, with all due respect, I think we are basically in agreement that 1) Cleaner/PhantomReference are just an optimized version of finalize (and there exists a lemma that _optimized_ **does not** automatically mean _better_.) 2) Deprecation of `finalize` was an act of angst and desperation against n00bs. It's not actually going anywhere and it's not any less correct than Cleaner/PhantomReference.

Comment: And don't get me wrong, I did just discover the utility of an efficient, flexible alternative-finalization solution after studying Netty. Netty has a reference-counted manual memory management system on top of native memory, and it uses WeakReferences (strangely, not PhantomReferences) in an _optional_ and _sampling_ memory leak detection strategy. Using `finalize` would have been too slow. Nevertheless, that's a rare case, and it is good advice to avoid unnecessary optimization.

Comment: Well, `finalize()` should never have existed. And it’s never too late to admit that something was a bad idea. Regarding, `WeakReference` vs. `PhantomReference`, I also used `WeakReference` when I truly needed such thing. As said, before Java 9, phantom references were not automatically cleared, requiring the referent to get collected in a second cycle, which made it less efficient. Besides that, the only difference is that the object must be finalized before the phantom reference gets enqueued, so when you don’t use finalizers, there is no difference anymore.

Comment: Sigh, or perhaps these are all bad ideas. Instead, what should exist is a built-in, optimized, special-purpose mechanism for debugging resource leaks akin to Netty's `ResourceLeakDetector` followed by an expectation that leaks don't exist. Then we wouldn't need finalizers at all. Or better yet, we could have built-in automatic reference counting. Now that would be helpful.

Comment: The `Cleaner` seems to be a rather poor replacement for the safety net that `finalize` provided, requiring a thread per type of object that needs such a safety net.  At the very least the standard implementation could have provided a shared `Cleaner` before Java apps of any size start having dozens of junk threads hanging around to clean instances of a single class.

Comment: @john16384 a single `Cleaner` can be used for different type of objects. Frameworks are free to define their shared `Cleaner`; that's not different to `ExecutorService`. But making the cleaning actions of entirely unrelated resources depend on each other (a long running cleaning action can delay other cleaning actions) brings you to the very problems of `finalize()`. But more than often, the error starts with thinking that there was a need for such a "safety net" for a particular application.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by [Elliott in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879761/should-java-9-cleaner-be-preferred-to-finalization/52879924#comment92673037_52879761), moving ahead with Java9+, the `Object.finalize` is deprecated and hence it makes more sense to implement methods using `Cleaner`. Also, from the release notes :

> The `java.lang.Object.finalize` method has been deprecated. The
>   finalization mechanism is inherently problematic and can lead to
>   performance issues, deadlocks, and hangs. The `java.lang.ref.Cleaner`
>   and `java.lang.ref.PhantomReference` provide more flexible and efficient
>   ways to release resources when an object becomes unreachable.

Details in Bug Database - [JDK-8165641](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8165641)

Comment: I'm just going to copy&paste my comment to Elliot: Well, I don't disagree that finalization can have all of the listed problems, but I fail to see why Cleaner is "more flexible and efficient." Performance issues? Check. Deadlocks/hangs? Why not. Errors causing resource leaks? Of course. Cancelability? I don't see any Cleanable.cancel. Order guarantees? None at all. Timing guarantees? Forget about it. Seriously, wtf are they trying to sell us?

Comment: Not very familiar with the tone, yet one of the reasons to deprecate it from the linked documents for one to read http://mindprod.com/jgloss/finalize.html

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky [`Cleanable.clean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.Cleanable.html#clean()): *Unregisters the cleanable and invokes the cleaning action.* That's what you should call, e.g. in the `close()` method of you resource class. Then, the GC is only needed if calling `close()` has been forgotten. But when closing correctly, you get timely cleanup and unregistration, regardless of when the next GC will happen.

Comment: @Holger Yup, I noticed that reading the code and included it in my answer. `clean()` calls `Reference.clear()` which prevents the reference from enqueing on the ReferenceQueue and also removes references to it so it can be GC'd in the first pass. `Finalizer` could offer the same feature because it also inherits `Reference`, except for the fact that there is no way to access it.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky the fact that `finalize()` is implemented with a special `Reference` object, is an implementation detail. But worse than not being able to opt out, is the lack of control over the registration. An object of a class with a nontrivial `finalize()` method is registered when the `Object()` constructor has been executed, before the resource has been allocated, at a time when the object is not even initialized. There’s the so-called finalizer attack to get hands on an uninitialized or invalid object, even when the constructor threw an exception.

Comment: Could anyone explain how to use PhantomReference and PhantomReference + Cleaner ?

Answer (score -5):

Java 9's Cleaner is very similar to traditional finalization (as implemented in OpenJDK), and almost everything (good or bad) that can be said about finalization can be said about Cleaner. Both rely on the garbage collector to place `Reference` objects on a `ReferenceQueue` and use a separate thread to run the cleanup methods.

The three main differences are that Cleaner uses `PhantomReference` instead of what is essentially a `WeakReference` (phantom reference doesn't allow you to access the object, which ensures it cannot be made reachable, ie zombified), uses a separate thread per Cleaner with a customizable ThreadFactory, and allows the PhantomReferences to be cleared (ie, cancelled) manually and never enqueued.

This provides performance advantages when heavy use is made of Cleaner/finalization. (Unfortunately, I don't have benchmarks to say how much of an advantage.) However, making heavy use of finalization is not normal.

For the normal things that `finalize` is used for--ie, a last-resort clean-up mechanism for native resources implemented with small, final objects that hold the minimum necessary state, provide `AutoCloseable`, and aren't allocated millions per second--there is no practical difference between the two approaches other than usage differences (in some aspects `finalize` is simpler to implement, in others `Cleaner` helps avoid mistakes). Cleaner doesn't provide any additional guarantees or behaviors (such as guaranteeing that cleaners will run prior to the process exiting--which is essentially impossible to guarantee anyway).

**However, `finalize` has been deprecated.** So that's that, I guess. Kind of a dick move. Perhaps the JDK developers are thinking, <s>"why should the JDK provide a native mechanism that can easily be implemented as a library"</s> "n00bs. n00bs everywhere. n00bs, stop using finalize, we hate you so much." It is a good point--and yet, I can't imagine `finalize` actually disappearing.

A good article that talks about finalization and  outlines how alternative-finalization works can be found here: [How to Handle Java Finalization's Memory-Retention Issues](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/finalization-137655.html) It paints in broad strokes how Cleaner works.

An example of the kind of code that might use Cleaner or PhantomReference instead of finalize is Netty's reference-counted manual management of direct (non-heap) memory. There, a lot of finalizeable objects get allocated and the alternative-finalization mechanism adopted by Netty makes sense. However, Netty goes a step farther and doesn't create a Reference for each reference-counted object unless the leak detector is set to its highest sensitivity. During usual operation it either doesn't use finalization at all (because if there is a resource leak, you're going to find out about it eventually anyway) or uses sampling (attaches clean-up code to a small fraction of allocated objects).

Netty's [ResourceLeakDetector](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/ResourceLeakDetector.java) is much cooler than `Cleaner`.